# Facing memory leak for SSL with python3.8, twisted 20.3.0, OpenSSL 1.1.1g

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, twisted.web

I am new to python. I am getting memory leak for HTTPs requests. Seems something is wrong around SSL. I am using python3.8, twisted 20.3.0, OpenSSL 1.1.1g.

I tried downgrading openssl version to 1.0.2k, downgraded twisted to 19.10.0 but nothing worked. I saw continuous increase in memory usage. Once I stop the python process memory usage return backs to normal.

Also, I do not see increase in memory usage when I comment the code for HTTPs requests. i.e.
reactor.connectSSL(host, port, factory, contextFactory)

How can I reduce the scope of issue. How to identity which of the following is the reason for memory leak?

- OpenSSL(c library)
- pyopenssl (python module)
- python 3.8
- twisted

It would be great if somebody will help in getting this issue resolved or put some light on it.

Comment: I can see memory leak in valgrind output:

==30492== LEAK SUMMARY:

==30492==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30492==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30492==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==30492==    still reachable: 143,221 bytes in 6,508 blocks

==30492==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks